# How to re-download offloaded app (with data) from my old iPad to new iPad

Tags: applications, data-transfer, ipados

I searched a lot for this question; found this question ([How do I transfer app data from my old iPad to my new iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10023/how-do-i-transfer-app-data-from-my-old-ipad-to-my-new-ipad)) but it's from nearly a decade ago, so it may not be relevant.

I will be buying a new iPad (2020) and trading in my old one (from 2017). There is one app (Multicraft, an offline version of Minecraft) which I have spent a lot of time using, and considering the amount of time I have spent creating things with this app, I'd like to keep all the data.

My question is: How do I re-download the offloaded app (with data) from my old iPad to new iPad?
Has anyone done this recently and confirmed that their method works with various types of apps?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer from the original post should still be correct: backup your old iPad, restore onto your new iPad.

Comment: I agree with @nohillside - There’s no harm in trying a backup first to see that it all migrates. Keep the old iPad running in the interim.